# Images don't update after being edited

Tags: images, uploads, media-library

I have **many** pictures on my site and after posting for a while, I realized that I should have watermarked them. So I did just that, I downloaded all the images and watermarked them. I uploaded a few of them back up to the site using FTP and replacing the images in the wp-content folder and I cleared my cache but the images dont show the updated version with the watermark. Is there no way to edit the image? Do I have to manually re-add the images to WP using the upload button on the page?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

When you upload an image via the media library, additional sizes are created: large, medium, thumbnail, plus any additional sizes defined by plugins or your theme. If your theme displays any sizes other than the original, un-resized image, you'll have to regenerate those additional sizes to see any changes take effect.

If this is the case for you, the [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin should work for you.